# simples solution to subset max data with multiple condition passed

Tags: r

I want to subset data from data frame with multiple conditions where one of them is `max` or `min`. Here is what i mean with use of `mtcars`:

`mtcars[mtcars$qsec==max(mtcars$qsec),]`

output is:

```
          mpg cyl  disp hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8 95 3.92 3.15 22.9  1  0    4    2
```

now I want to get fastest car (`mtcars$qsec==max(mtcars$qsec)`) but only from cars that have 5 gears or more:

`mtcars[mtcars$gear>=5 & mtcars$qsec==max(mtcars$qsec),]`

The output is empty table...

BEFORE YOU ANSWER: I can find a way to solve this by myself, for example doing this:

```
my_mtcars=mtcars[mtcars$gear>=5,]
my_mtcars[my_mtcars$qsec==max(my_mtcars$qsec),]
```

out:

```
              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
Lotus Europa 30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2
```

However, in this particular situation code simplicity is most crucial factor for me. Can you propose any solution that can be done in one line of code and do not include anything more complex? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `subset` to *filter multiple conditions*.

```
subset(subset(mtcars, gear>=5), qsec==max(qsec))
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
#Lotus Europa 30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2

subset(mtcars[mtcars$gear>=5,], qsec==max(qsec))
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
#Lotus Europa 30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2
```

Or for many depending conditions you can use `Reduce`.

```
conditions <- alist(gear>=5, qsec==max(qsec))
Reduce(function(x,y) subset(x,eval(y)), conditions, mtcars)
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
#Lotus Europa 30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2
```

Or storing where `gear>=5` and using this to calculate `max`.

```
i <- mtcars$gear>=5
mtcars[i & mtcars$qsec==max(mtcars$qsec[i]),]
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
#Lotus Europa 30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2
```

Or using `which` and `which.max`.

```
i <- which(mtcars$gear>=5)
mtcars[i[which.max(mtcars$qsec[i])],]
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
#Lotus Europa 30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a number of ways. One can be,

```
filter(mtcars[mtcars$gear >= 5 ,], qsec == max(qsec))

#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
#  30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R solution using `order`, i.e.,

```
res <- head(mtcars[order(mtcars$gear>=5,mtcars$qsec,decreasing = T),],1)
```

such that

```
> res
              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
Lotus Europa 30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use a package, this is pretty simple.

The catch is that this will not keep row names. I never have row names so I consider this a decent solution, but if you do, you will have to account for that first (i.e., `tibble::rownames_to_column()`).

```
library(dplyr)

slice(filter(mtcars, gear >= 5), which.max(qsec))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this as a separate answer because it may or may not be helpful depending on the use case. This has the same disclaimer about `rownames` being dropped.

You can make a fairly simple function to allow you to filter sequentially.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

filter_nested <- function(.data, ...) {

  dots <- enquos(...)

  for (current_filter in seq_along(dots)) {
    .data <- .data %>% 
      filter(!!dots[[current_filter]])
  }

  .data

}
```

When you apply this, it will go left to right from the input, applying the filter. So your code itself would be extremely simple.

```r
filter_nested(mtcars, gear >= 5, qsec == max(qsec))

#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2
```

If you wanted two criteria to be applied at the same time, you could combine them into a single criteria with `&`.

```r
filter_nested(mtcars, gear >= 5 & hp > 150, qsec == max(qsec))

#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 19.7   6  145 175 3.62 2.77 15.5  0  1    5    6
```